# tf.layers.batch_normalization throws data_type error while using Tensorflow v 1.4 but not 1.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

The following statement,
 bn1 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=conv1, axis=1, training = is_training)
Throws an error: InternalError: The CPU implementation of FusedBatchNorm only supports NHWC tensor format for now.
on my CPU using tensorflow v:1.4
However, I've ensured that the code uses data in NHWC format. The same piece of code works on my friend's CPU, the only difference being he's using Tensorflow v.1.0 and the code runs smoothly without issues.

I tried to look up tensorflow documentation,
https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide
It suggests feeding in two extra arguments: fused=True, data_format='NHWC'.

However, as per
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization
there is no such provision for the 2 above mentioned arguments. And in fact, the code throws an error saying batch_normalization received an unexpected argument.

Any responses on the potential reason behind the issue and how I could get around it without rolling back my Tensorflow version (because that would be absurd) are most welcome.
Thank you so uch for your time and effort.